# heroku rake db:migrate failing - how to diagnose/fix?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rake, rails-migrations, dbmigrate

```
heroku rake db:migrate --trace --app app-name
  !   Internal server error
```

This was working fine before.

How to diagnose this?

`rake db:migrate` works fine on my local db. There is no entry in the log. VERSION=xxx did not help either.

Using rake 0.8.7.

Comment: A friend is experiencing similar problems right now with the same problem - I'd say it's a platform problem.

Comment: Yup, I'm also having this issue.

Comment: Ok thanks. Btw, I updated rake to 0.9.2.2 and that did not help. I guess I chose the wrong day to release an update...

Comment: I've worked around this solution in the meantime, you can run a migration via the heroku scheduler, works fine here.

Comment: OK, it's fixed now. Also, don't switch to rake 0.9.2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok heroku support already helped me out!

Here the workaround

"try running the migration from a bash dyno?"

```
$ heroku run bash
```

"Then just run your migration command (something like):"

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

This was a good work around I could migrate my application.

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem earlier, I assume it's a server issue.

To get around the problem:

I added the heroku scheduled addon, added a scheduled job for 'rake db:migrate':

https://heroku-scheduler.herokuapp.com/dashboard#

It allows you to run the job on the web interface, as well as confirm the output was successful.

Not a solution I know, but should get around the issue for the moment.